# Electron application is not closing

Tags: javascript, electron

When I click on the cross button of the electron application, it is not closing the application, showing error in the console

```
[Intervention] Blocked attempt to show a 'beforeunload' confirmation panel for a frame that never had a user gesture since its load. https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5082396709879808
```

I am using the below code for closing the app

```
mainWindow.on('close', function(e){
    var choice = require('electron').dialog.showMessageBoxSync(this,
        {
          type: 'question',
          buttons: ['Yes', 'No'],
          title: 'Confirm',
          message: 'Are you sure you want to quit?'
       });
       if(choice == 1){
         e.preventDefault();
       }
  });
```

Comment: Which os are you using? Win or Mac

Comment: Also, is the MessageBox shown or not?

Comment: I am using Windows 10 and the Message box is showing but after click in yes, the application remains open.

Answer (score 1):

In short, I guess maybe you add this code for returning false on default `beforeunload` event handler in somewhere, like this

```js
window.onbeforeunload = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    event.returnValue = false;
}
```

remove it, it might be work fine.

Because it will trigger on closing window, and in [spec](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/browser-window#%E4%BA%8B%E4%BB%B6-close).
There might be something wrong on dealing with native browser and close event.